# pull out the count of items from a Generic itemlist in .net

Tags: json, .net, asp.net-mvc

```
JsonResult result = null;
LanguageTranslation handler = new LanguageTranslation();
result = Json(handler.GetLanguageTranslationData(EnglishText), 
JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
var check = result.Data;
return result;
```

From the above code I need to have the count of items in `result.Data`.

Answer (score 0):

The [Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.json) method returns a [JsonResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.jsonresult) object with the [Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.jsonresult.data) that was supplied in the method call.

If you need to write some code that interacts with that object, why not first assign it to a variable?

```
LanguageTranslation handler = new LanguageTranslation();
var data = handler.GetLanguageTranslationData(EnglishText);
// Work with data here...
var result = Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
// Or work with data here...
return result;
```